# How to send livestream video from UWP to WEB App?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, uwp, raspberry-pi3

which is the best way to send live stream video from UWP app to Web MVC application ? I am doing my Final year project. My 1st task is to send the livestream vedio from raspberry pi using UWP app and display that stream in Web MVC application ? please guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to establish a connection between UWP and a web server then pass video streams, you can use [StreamWebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamwebsocket)

After establishing the connection, you can write the video stream obtained by the local capture camera to `OuputStream`, pass it to the server, and then send it to other devices through the server.

These may help you:

- [WebSockets document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets)
- [WebSocket sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSocket)

Best regards.